# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-grid

I am getting this error while running Selenium grid for the first time:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   service: ChromeDriverService.

Please help and suggest!

Below is the code:

```
WebDriver driver;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
String URL = "http://www.google.com";
String Node = "http://192.168.22.139:5555/wd/hub";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.HIGH_SIERRA);
WebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node),cap);
remoteWebDriver.get(URL);
Thread.sleep(5000);
remoteWebDriver.quit();
}
```

Comment: What is the browser and ChromeDriver version. This generally happens due to binaries mismatch.